# Unable to get specific value from post meta

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, post-meta

I am using `get_post_meta()` to retrieve a custom meta field value from a given post.

The custom meta box has a parent checkbox which has 3 child checkboxes. I want to get the values of both parent and child.

- Parent checkbox
  Enable Protection for this post
- Child checkboxes: (a) Level 1  (b) Level 2  (c) Level 3

here is the screenshot of the metabox. https://www.screencast.com/t/7fA19sCoe2yD

The code I am using is:

```
$meta = get_post_meta( '8142', '_key_value', true );
foreach( $meta as $m ){
  echo $m['protect']; 
  echo $m['selectedlevels'];
}
```

But it only echo the `$m['protect']` which is also the parent checkbox. How can I output its child checkboxes too?

if I `var_dump`, it returns the following value:

`array(2) { ["protect"]=> bool(true) ["selectedlevels"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(2) } }`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Not all the checkboxes are going to be saved, only the selected checkboxes will be saved, as your `var_dump()` shows.

Comment: sorry about the confusion. Yes you are right. I want to get the values of only checked ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `var_dump()` I can only assume the checked values are in the `selecteclevels` array which you can get by looping through the array:

```
foreach( $meta['selectedlevels'] as $level ) {
    echo $level;
}
```

Or using array indices: `echo $meta['selectedlevels'][0]`. Note, `get_post_meta()` may return nothing, and you should check if the `selectedlevels` index even exists your returned variable.